# Let $X$ be the number of baskets made in $10$ throws. (a) Find the probability mass function of $X$.

Tags: probability

> Assuming that a basketball player has a probability of $0.6$ of making a
>   basket. Let $X$ be the number of baskets made in $10$ throws.
>   (a) Find the probability mass function of $X$.
>   (b) Find $P(X = 3)$. [Use R to find the answer]
>   (c) Find $P(X ≤ 3)$. [Use R to find the answer]
>   (d) Find $P(X \text{ is even})$. [Use R to find the answer]

I'm having trouble with this because we have not learned how to use `R` yet in class and I'm terribly stuck on it! For the pmf, out of $10$ throws, there is a $60\%$ chance of making the so does that mean when $X = 0, p(x) = 0$ when $X = 6, p(x) = 0.6$ and when $X = 4, p(x) = 0.6$? Is that how to construct the pmf ? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You were given a hint earlier. If we assume independence between shots, then
notice that we have $n = 10$ independent trials (shots) with probability $p = 0.6$ of success (making a shot). Notice that these are the conditions to conclude that the number of shots made $X$ follows a binomial distribution $X\sim\text{Bin}(4,.6)$.

Now that you know the distribution, what is the pmf?

Verify that you have the correct pmf by computing 
$$P(X= 3).$$
Using `R`, we have $P(X= 3)$ is

```
> dbinom(3, 10, .6)
[1] 0.04246733
```

You can google more about using `R` to calculate various things for the well known distribution. You can also enter `?dbinom` or `help(dbinom)` on the console for more information on the binomial distribution.

I'll leave b) and c) code for you to figure out. For b) you're going to want to look at `pbinom`.